# How to check output dynamically with Luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I realize I likely need to use dynamic requirements to accomplish the following task, however I have not been able to wrap my head around what this would look like in practice.

The goal is to use Luigi to generate data and add it to a database, without knowing ahead of time what data will be generated.

Take the following example using mongodb:

```
import luigi
from uuid import uuid4
from luigi.contrib import mongodb
import pymongo

# Make up IDs, though in practice the IDs may be generated from an API
class MakeID(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write(','.join([str(uuid4()) for e in range(10)]))

    # Write the data to file
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('data.csv')


class ToDataBase(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return MakeID()

    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as f:
            ids = f.read().split(',')

        # Add some fake data to simulate generating new data 
        count_data = {key: value for value, key in enumerate(ids)}
        # Add data to the database
        self.output().write(count_data)

    def output(self):
        # Attempt to read non-existent file to get the IDs to check if task is complete
        with self.input().open('r') as f:
            valid_ids = f.read().split(',')
        client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',
                                     27017,
                                     ssl=False)

        return mongodb.MongoRangeTarget(client,
                                        'myDB',
                                        'myData',
                                        valid_ids,
                                        'myField')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

The goal is to obtain data, modify it and then add it to a database.

The above code fails when run because the `output` method of `ToDataBase` runs before the `require` method so the while the function has access to the input, the input does not yet exist. Regardless I still need to check to be sure that the data was added to the database.

This [github issue](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/2204) is close to what I am looking for, though as I mentioned I have not been able to figure out dynamic requirements for this use case in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a third task (in the example `Dynamic`) that yields the task that is waiting on dynamic input and making the dependency a parameter rather than a `requires` method.

```
class ToDatabase(luigi.Task):
    fp = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        with open(self.fp, 'r') as f:
            valid_ids = [str(e) for e in f.read().split(',')]
        client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017, ssl=False)
        return mongodb.MongoRangeTarget(client, 'myDB', 'myData',
                                        valid_ids, 'myField')

    def run(self):
        with open(self.fp, 'r') as f:
            valid_ids = [str(e) for e in f.read().split(',')]
        self.output().write({k: 5 for k in valid_ids})


class Dynamic(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return self.input()

    def requires(self):
        return MakeIDs()

    def run(self):
        yield(AddToDatabase(fp=self.input().path))
```